# How to make ScrollArea for Image or Text in Flash CC Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, createjs, flash-cc

I want to make a masked area with images/text and control it with a scrollbar in flash cc html5 canvas. Anybody knows how to do it?

Thanks,

Rodrigo

Comment: This is a fairly complex thing to do in Canvas.. Any reason you are using Canvas instead of HTML DOM?

Comment: Well, it has specific fonts and very rich formatted text and images to scroll. The client wants the look identical to original swf file.